# Where does it state that Empress Tianzi's real name is Jiang Lihua?

Tags: code-geass

In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Code_Geass_characters#Jiang_Lihua_(Tianzi)) and [Wikia](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Empress_Tianzi) for Empress Tianzi, it states that her real name is **Jiang Lihua**.

Where does this information come from? It is never stated as such in *R2* so, what side information conveys this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Empress Tianzi's real name is never stated in the anime series; it's only stated in the *Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion R2* official guidebook.**

According to [pixiv encyclopedia (Japanese)](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E8%92%8B%E9%BA%97%E8%8F%AF),

> 中華連邦の頂点に君臨する天子の本名である。この本名はTV本編には出ていないが、最終回前に発売されたアニメディアの付録のコードギアスの小冊子にて判明された。 [...]
>
> [...] Tianzi's real name. Even though her real name does not appear in the TV anime, it was stated in *Code Geass*'s appendix booklet that was released before the last episode. [...]

Researching further, based from [tare-pannda's blog post (Japanese)](http://tare-pannda.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2008-10-30), her real name was stated in [***Code Geass Lelouch of the Rebellion R2 The Complete Official Guide Book*** (Japanese)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4048542494) where the blogger mentioned the content of the book:

> DRAMATIS　PERSONAE　～キャラクター解説～
> [...]●天子（蒋麗華）[...]
>
> DRAMATIS PERSONAE ~Character Explanation~
> [...]・Tianzi (Jiang Lihua) [...]